# How does Android perform Data-Wifi Switch

Tags: networking, mobile-network

I am trying to learn from Android source on Data-Wifi automatic switch.

The closest I can get is DataCommand and WifiCommand, they seem to switch network preference (through ConnectivityManager), by which I suppose can switch active interface. But I cannot find where these commands are actually used.

http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/DataCommand.java

http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/cmds/svc/src/com/android/commands/svc/WifiCommand.java

Can any one has experience in Android framework point for me where to look at?

I know this might be the wrong place to ask source code question, but any help is appreciated.